# Can't find spark submit when typing spark-shell

Tags: linux, scala, apache-spark

I've been following this tutorial to install spark for scala:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_spark/apache_spark_installation.htm

However, When I try to run `spark-shell` I receive this error in my console.

```
/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-shell: line 57: /usr/local/spark/bin/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
```

My bashrc looks like this:

```
export PATH = $PATH:/usr/local/spark/bin
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/scala/bin
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python
```

So what am I getting wrong? I've installed spark for python before but now I'm trying to use scala. Is spark confusing the variables? Thanks.

Comment: You have one `bin` too many in the path it's searching:  `/usr/local/spark/bin/bin/spark-submit` should be `/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit`. What is your spark home?

Comment: My ```SPARK_HOME``` is set as the same as my ```PATH```, where my ```spark-shell``` executable is

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have one `bin` too many in the path it's searching:

```
/usr/local/spark/bin/bin/spark-submit
```

should be

```
/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit
```

The `SPARK_HOME` should be `/usr/local/spark/` in your case, not `/usr/local/spark/bin/` as it seems to be the case now.

Answer (score 7):

Based on @Wilmerton's answer, I came up with the following working configuration inside my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Apache Spark stuff
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/scala/bin
export PATH=$PATH:${SPARK_HOME}/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME
```

(I installed `default-jdk` with `apt-get install default-jdk` and `aptitude search jdk` yields the following entries with different from `p` status:

```
i   default-jdk                                        - Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit
i A default-jdk-headless                               - Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit (headless)
i A openjdk-8-jdk                                      - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
i A openjdk-8-jdk-headless                             - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
iBA openjdk-8-jre                                      - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
i A openjdk-8-jre-headless                             - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
i   openjdk-9-jdk-headless                             - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
iB  openjdk-9-jre                                      - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
i A openjdk-9-jre-headless                             - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
```

)

Comment: Isn't `JAVA_HOME` widely expected to point to the java install directory and not the jre directory? So it should be be `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` not `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the second environment variable in your bashrc to this

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/scala/bin
```

My .bash_profile is pretty much the same as yours except I use `Path` instead of `SCALA_HOME`

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem,
i solved it this way

```
!sudo apt update
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.2.1/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!tar xf spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!pip install -q findspark
!pip install pyspark

import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2"

import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()

from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, SparkSession
from typing import List
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


spark = SparkSession \
       .builder \
       .appName("Our First Spark example") \
       .getOrCreate()

spark
```

Comment: This answer lacks any supporting information. It is also a python solution to a scala-based question.

Answer (score 0):

Had kinda the same problem. After unzipping the downloaded spark package, an env variable called `SPARK_HOME` has to be created and set to the path of the unzipped spark package. In my case I set this env variable to the parent directory of the unzipped package and not the actual package. so when `spark-shell` was being executed, it could not find the shell file to execute the command.

For better clarification, checkout the `bin/spark-shell` file after the package is unzipped. There you will find the `${SPARK_HOME}` being used in the code.